# Django REST framework: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am learning [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/), and trying to print `print request.query_params`. But got error:

```
    print request.query_params
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'
```

Codes:

```
class CourseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request.user
        print 'CourseDetailView dispatch:', request.META
        #print request.data
        """
        print 'parsers', request.parsers
        print request.accepted_renderer
        print 'authenticators', request.authenticators
        """
        #print 'accepted_media_type', request.accepted_media_type
        print request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
        print 'method', request.method
        print 'content_type', request.content_type
        print 'query_params'
        print request.query_params # Here

        return super(CourseDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Part of my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
]

# DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: May also work for some use cases `request.GET['my-param']` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dispatch` is the first method called in a class based view, and it's where all the setup happens - including, in the case of an API view, the wrapping of the Django request object with the DRF extensions. By overriding it you've prevented any of that code from running, so you just have the basic Django request.

Generally you should avoid overriding `dispatch`. Use a more appropriate method, eg `get`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess so. But I am interested to know how the  request go to each middleware/function one by one and when. For example, when the request is processed by the dispatch function. How to know it? Thanks

Comment: @BAE The original `request` passes through all middlewares top to bottom in your `MIDDLEWARES` setting BEFORE the view's dispatch. DRF's `APIView`'s `dispatch` then assigns [`self.request`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L466) to an instance of its own extended `Request` class.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman It's been a while since you're answer but I'd be interested in where in the documentation that would be available from? I.e. that `dispatch` is the first method called in class based views.