# Pass request to django inherited classes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-activity-stream

I am overriding some methods of a popular package, `django-activity-stream` (I think the package is mostly irrelevant to this question).

from `app/urls.py` I call `TeamJSONActivityFeed`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(_(r'^feeds/organization/(?P<organization_id>.+)$'), TeamJSONActivityFeed.as_view(name='organization_stream')),
    ...
]
```

TeamJSONactivityFeed then calls 'pass', which I am not too familiar with, and inherits from two other classes, `OrganizationStreamMixin` and `JSONActivityFeed`.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class TeamJSONActivityFeed(OrganizationStreamMixin, JSONActivityFeed):
    """
    JSON feed of Activity for a custom stream. self.name should be the name of the custom stream as defined in the Manager
    and arguments may be passed either in the url or when calling as_view(...)
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    pass
```

My issue is that I cannot seem to access/pass the request object in/to these inherited classes. How would I go about passing this in? Right now, `self.request.user` and `request.user` are `AnonymousUser` objects.

```
class OrganizationStreamMixin(object):
    name = None

    def get_object(self,request):
        # this is printing Anonymous User
        pprint(str(self.request.user))
        pprint(str(request.user))
        return

    def get_stream(self):
        return getattr(Action.objects, self.name)

    def items(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_stream()(*args[1:], **kwargs)


class JSONActivityFeed(AbstractActivityStream, View):
    """
    Feed that generates feeds compatible with the v1.0 JSON Activity Stream spec
    """
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        for i, v in kwargs.items():
            print ("    ", i, ": ", v)

        return HttpResponse(self.serialize(request, *args, **kwargs),
                            content_type='application/json')

    def serialize(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pprint(str(self.request.user))

        items = self.items(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return json.dumps({
            'totalItems': len(items),
            'items': [self.format(action) for action in items]
        })
```

Note: I am a bit of a django/python noob, but I am sure I am calling this properly from the front end. Similar requests have access to the request user.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit of confusion. You do have access to the request object otherwise it would raise an error for trying to access `.user` on `None`. If you're concerned about it being an AnonymousUser instance, then authenticate before accessing that view. If you need to prevent AnonymousUser instances from being able to access that view, then wrap the view with the `login_required` decorator.

**Edit**

You're overriding the `dispatch` method without calling `super`. That could be the problem.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I edited the question with the code now, but I had previously tried adding token authentication. I added it back, and passing in a token and am authenticated (as verified by other views), and am still getting Anonymous user for this view.

Comment: It may be due to overriding the dispatch method without calling super.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll play around with that, and post back here if I get it. My guess is it has something to do with me strictly using exclusively generic DRF views prior to this, and something being misconfigured for standard views.

Comment: I ended up wrapping it as a DRF view, instead of just View, then had to overwrite get instead of dispatch :). The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892602/django-rest-framework-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-query-params also helped me get there. Thank you @schillingt!

Comment: @ambe5960 did you ever figure out why it was not working? I am in same boat right now. All APIs working fine but for my API related to activity stream I am getting anonymous user.

Comment: @Pooja See my last comment. I think it had to do with it not being a DRF view, and presumably something about session authentication not being enabled. I am/was using tokenauth.